# How would you neutralise an invulnerable flying human

Tags: weapons, flight, trans-humanism

They seem to fly through levitation and while they are affected by external force, eg you could push them over. They are not hindered by any attempt at damaging them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do we have to kill the flying person or just stop them from moving?

Comment: What ideas have you tried?  It seems trivial to do this to me, which implies that you likely have constraints in mind which have not been written into the question.

Comment: Use a big net, like catching a butterflies.

Answer (score 2):

Noting different compared to regular jailing. Catch him using a steel net, pull using winches and put him into a prison that he cannot lift. Should work unless he can lift huge construction machines that you would be using to reel him in. In that case, use a bigger machine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that this human can just **fly** and is **invulnerable** (can't be damaged) without any other powers this is quite simple.

To neutralize is to render (something) ineffective or harmless by applying an opposite force or effect.

If the human is average in other regards all you need to do is to contain and/or restrain him. This could range from a straight jacket to solitary confinement. Depending on how much he can lift while flying to bring the man down might include heavy nets, ropes, or missiles (he can't be harmed but the force of an explosion could knock him down).

If the goal is to kill the man I think suffocation or drowning would be the best options.

Comment: Starvation will also work. If you can't catch him just prevent him getting food by constantly chasing him.

Answer (score 0):

Dump something thick and sticky (and probably hot) on their head.  In large quantities.  Bonus points if it sets up thickly after a bit, double bonus points if it sets up *hard*.

Well, you mentioned that they can be pushed over.  Gushing a large volume of thick, sticky liquid (I'm thinking heated resin, or tar, or something of the sort) straight down on their head is likely to a) push them straight downwards, and b) distract the *hexandaquarter* out of them.  Flying will be somewhere between harder to outright impossible with that kind of weight and force shoving them downwards, and the distraction quality means they might not even try for a bit till they figure out what's going on.  You didn't mention superstrength to move with it hindering them, or even to get it off them - but even if they have it, the basic idea should work if you scale up the stickiness/thickness to blind, distract, and hinder while you set up for the kind of imprisonment mentioned in other answers.  Since the hard part will be catching them, I think.

The bonus points, of stiffening or setting up when cooled (or dried, but drying *takes longer*) - means that their movement will be hindered, their limbs stiff and slow, they will have to carry extra weight when levitating, they will have a hard time seeing and possibly breathing (of course, they can wipe it off when still fairly liquid - but this adds to the distraction element and gives it more *time* to set up).

Additionally, it is possible that this will hit a limit on their invulnerability.  They may need to breathe - and thick sticky stuff setting on their face will endanger their airways.  They may have resistance to hard blows, but maybeso not to higher temperatures - even if they escape actual burns because of invulnerable skin, what about heat stroke, or heat exhaustion?  how high a temp can their brain take, or their blood, when there's enough volume and insulation to prevent them from cooling off?

How to make it work - probably a pipe, and a building, and something to lure them to the spot where it's set up?  The pipe would let not just a large quantity, but a continuing volume.  Or if you've got really good aim, maybe something dropped from a helicopter or plane (though the volume would be less, maybe something even thicker to begin with to compensate?)  If they can fly, then a situation where they're talking to someone on the ground might work, since they might stay in place because they would be "secure" in knowing that the only way to reach them is from above, and they're invulnerable anyway if something is dropped on them.

Alternatively, you might be able to shove him into, or dunk him under, a pool of the stuff - but you would be relying on his overconfidence-because-invulnerability to let himself be trapped in that way.   Will he stay still while a cement mixer tips its contents over him?  only if he's really arrogant.  But a pipe might not be noticed if it's cleverly set up and disguised.